# しばしばとたびたびの違いを教えていただけないでしょうか

Tags: word-choice

しばしばとたびたびの違いは何ですか?

JLPT N2 の語彙の本でこの問題がありました。

> 使い方が正しくない言葉の代わりに他の言葉を書きなさい。
>
> > 人というものは、たびたび自分の失敗を人のせいにする。

答えの本を見ると、たびたびの代わりにしばしばが正しいそうです。でも私はたびたびとしばしばは同じ使い方だと思いましたので、答えはさっぱりわからないです。違いを教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 難しい問題ですね。「たびたび」は正式な文章に使うのには「しばしば」よりふさわしいようですね。したがって答えは「たびたび」なのでしょうね。文章以外ではたびたびとしばしばは、大体同じように使われているような気がします。設問は正式な文章上使い方が正しくない言葉を選んで下さいとしても良いような気が...。

Answer (score 5):

- しばしば is rare in casual speech.

  > - その話ってたびたび<sub>(?しばしば)</sub>聞くよね。本当なの？
- Only たびたび can refer to relatively frequent but undesirable actions.

  > - たびたび<sub>(×しばしば)</sub>メールをして申し訳ありません。
  > - たびたび<sub>(×しばしば)</sub>の変更の要求があったせいで、とても時間がかかってしまった。
- たびたび tends to refer to repeated *actions* that occur in a certain period of time.

  > - 彼らは先生の話を、たびたび<sub>(?しばしば)</sub>笑いながら聞いていた。
- しばしば tends to refer to some generic characteristic which is not uncommon in a certain group.

  > - 日本語学習者にとって、漢字はしばしば<sub>(?たびたび)</sub>難しいことがある。
  > - 天才とはしばしば<sub>(×たびたび)</sub>変人でもある。
  > - 日本語の「青」は、しばしば<sub>(?たびたび)</sub>緑色も指す。

(`×` indicates incorrect or highly unnatural; `?` indicates questionable (to me))

Maybe the author of the textbook thought しばしば is correct because the sentence describes a general characteristic of human beings. That being said, I personally think 人というものはたびたび自分の失敗を人のせいにする is not wrong. For the reason I already mentioned, I feel たびたび sounds slightly more accusatory, whereas しばしば sounds slightly more matter-of-factly.

Comment: ありがとうございました。勉強になりました。